# Why is Account.Name represented in AccountHistory.Field as TextName and not Name?

Tags: field-history

### Given

- Enable field history tracking on `Name` fields:  `Account.Name`, `Opportunity.Name`, and `CustomObject__c.Name`
- Create a new Account, Opportunity, and CustomObject__c providing a value `Original`.
- Change the value in each of the records to `Original-Delta`

### When querying the respective history records

```
SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM AccountHistory WHERE CreatedDate = Today
```

> RESULT: Value of column: Field = `TextName`  ❗(*not* `Name`)

```
SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM OpportunityFieldHistory WHERE CreatedDate = Today
```

> RESULT: Value of column: Field = `Name` *as expected*

```
SELECT Id, Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM CustomObject__History WHERE CreatedDate = Today
```

> RESULT: Value of column: Field = `Name` *as expected*

### What's going on here?

- Why is `Account.Name` treated specially? *value of `AccountHistory.Field = TextName`*
- Is this a legacy of some long ago design decision?
- Are there other special cases out there?

### Why do I care?

Building a tool to selectively delete field history records given the API names of the parent field(s).  If parent field is `Name` but history field is `TextName` -- how do I know (progammatically)?